# Рандом выдаёт всегда отрицательные числа, с одинаковым количеством знаков

Tags: c++, c, файлы, случайные-числа

Рандом работает не совсем так, как нужно: выдаёт всегда отрицательные числа, с одинаковым количеством знаков. Как сделать так, чтобы рандом был более разнообразным?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

void numGen(ofstream &file, const int &inf, const int &sup, const int &n){
    int range = sup - inf + 1;
    srand(time(NULL));
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        file << inf + rand()%range << endl;
    }
}
int main()
{
    //...............
    int sup = 100000;
    int inf = -100000;
    int n = 10;
    //................
}
```

Пример вывода:

> -91328
>   -67532
>   -75698
>   -92597
>   -83996
>   -90853
>   -83616
>   -81149
>   -97221
>   -99874

Comment: Да уж, отрицательный рандом это не рандом. :-) Это какой-то печальный рандом.

Comment: Этот вопрос уже неизвестно сколько раз задавался. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/917318/%D0%A1%D0%B3%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE-%D0%BE%D1%82-100000-%D0%B4%D0%BE-1000000

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Сгенерированть рандомное число от 100000 до 1000000](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/917318/%d0%a1%d0%b3%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b5-%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%be-%d0%be%d1%82-100000-%d0%b4%d0%be-1000000)

Answer (score 6):

Ну давайте подумаем...

```
inf + rand()%range
```

То есть - `-100000 + rand()%200001`

Минимальное значение, которое можно получить - при `rand() == 0` - `-100000`. Все нормально.

А максимальное? Выведите разок, чему в вашей системе равно `RAND_MAX`, т.е. максимальное возвращаемое `rand()` значение. Например, у меня в VC++ 2017 оно равно 32767. Т.е. максимальное значение, которое вы можете получить - `32767-100000 = -67233`

Вопросы "почему" еще есть?

А "как сделать"? Воспользоваться тем, что у вас тэг `c++` и работать в возможностями современной стандартной библиотеки `<random>`. Например, так:

```
std::default_random_engine u;
std::uniform_int_distribution<> d(-100000,100000);
for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
    std::cout << d(u) << std::endl;
```

Comment: В вашем случае рандом выдаёт одни и те же числа. Как сделать так, чтобы при многократном использовании рандом выдавал разные числа?

Comment: Ай-я-яй, какой ужас! Все идут не в ногу, только старшина в ногу... Не говорите ерунды, и пишите программы правильно! https://ideone.com/K0CTvR Если не хотите приводить код - вангую: каждый раз **создаете engine заново**. Как если бы перед каждым вызовом `rand()` использовали `srand()`. Признавайтесь - начудили что-то вроде этого - https://ideone.com/AMetde ?

Comment: Эмм, нет, написал также, как и здесь ideone.com/K0CTvR . Причём выдаются те же самые числа.

Comment: А инициализировать генератор кто будет ? [пример](https://github.com/dimir29/RbkMoney.Bootcamp/blob/272c4c50ae3ce08ebf2f3780fa804ab254bef5cd/randomgenerator.cpp#L6)

Comment: Одни и те же числа подряд или одни и те же числа при разных запусках? Вы же нормально формулируйте! *" рандом выдаёт одни и те же числа"* - вот как это понимать? А если от запуска к запуску менять надо - ну, допишите `u.seed(std::random_device()());` после объявления `u`.

Comment: Дописал, также выдаются одни и те же числа (правда уже другой набор) при разных запусках.

Comment: Слушайте, дайте всю программу, какую вам надо, что там будет нужно еще сделать - потому что я так понимаю, что почитать и разобраться самому вам не светит, вам нужно, чтобы все сделали за вас... https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/random - тут документация. Не разберетесь - еще раз, я не собираюсь вам по мелочам каждый чих исправлять. Пишите уж все задание, все равно, похоже, справиться вам самостоятельно не судьба - нет такой привычки...